# What statistical testing to use for multiple distribution with majority zero values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, anova, multiple-comparisons

I have a list of 4 distributions of different sizes. Each of the distributions contains mostly 0s. I want to perform some statistical tests on the distributions to see if they are significantly different. What test should I use? Is Anova a good test for this situation?

Example data

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Different in what way?

Comment: @Dave The difference among them is just the size of the data. The number of data points varies from 25-40 across 4 distributions.

Comment: You want to test if they are significantly different. What does that mean to you?

Comment: @Dave I want to test if the frequency across 4 distributions is significantly different.

Comment: Frequency of what?

Comment: @Dave so each of the distributions comes from 4 different sets of samples. Here the frequency is the count of mutations on each sample for a particular type of mutation. So I want to test if mutation frequency is different across the type of samples.

Comment: Have you considered Poisson or negative binomial regression?